# Drawing a instantiation

Tags: vb.net, diagram, instantiation

I have look on the internet and I can find a example of a instantiation being drawn.  I have the flowing vb code:

```
Dim Me1 as cMe
Dim Me2 as cMe
Me1 = new cMe
Me2 = new cMe
Me1 = new cMe
```

How do i draw the instantiation of the above code?

Comment: Explain in detail what exactly you want to do

Comment: You know you can draw a UML for classes, I want to draw the Instantiation of the code above.

Comment: Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx

Comment: I am not asking how to draw the UML i can do that i want to know how do i draw the `instantiation.`

Comment: @JackGajanan There is `NOTHING` about instantiation on that webpage only how to draw a class diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Me1 <- cMe1  
 Me2 <- cMe2  
 Me1 <- cMe3  
        cMe1 -> disposed sometime later
```

Comment: You create three instances of `cMe` in the code; I just numbered them to distinguish them.